# How to retrieve images from Firebase in realtime in Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this code that retrieves only one image.
How can I edit it to retrieve more than an image?

And how can I attach a URL with the images in order to if the user clicks the image the URL will open?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    ImageView rImage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        rImage = findViewById(R.id.rImage);

        FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();

        DatabaseReference getImage = databaseReference.child("image");

        getImage.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                
                String link = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

                Picasso.get().load(link).into(rImage);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                // we are showing that error message in toast
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error Loading Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- we are using ImageView for displaying image-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to change your `ImageView` into an `ImageButton` so you can have a ClickListener and your image aswell

Comment: Why can't an `ImageView` be clickable?

Comment: It can, but the first idea i got was that one. You can make it clickable by adding `android:onClick` as atribute to your `ImageView` in your XML file.
But your image for the `ImageView` must already be stored in the drawable folder.

Comment: mmm, not quite if you set them the normal way, through code, instead of XML...

Answer (score 0):

First add a **button** in your `xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- we are using ImageView for displaying image-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now by that button `onclick` you will get your **image**.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    ImageView rImage;
    Button btn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        rImage = findViewById(R.id.rImage);
        //button reference
        btn= findViewById(R.id.btn);
        FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();

        DatabaseReference getImage = databaseReference.child("image");
        
        //setting onclick.
        btn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
             getImage.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                
                String link = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

                Picasso.get().load(link).into(rImage);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                // we are showing that error message in toast
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error Loading Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        });
       
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will add a button and it only replaces the previous image. what I want is to retrieve more than an Image at the same time in a list view.

Comment: Did you edit your question, when I posted this answer. You said you want to get image by onclick.

Comment: I didn't bro, that's my question from the beginning .